# How to formulate a convex expression to minimize the difference between Frobenius norm of a positive semidefinite matrix and a positive value

Tags: convex-optimization, nonconvex, semidefinite-programming

So what I am trying to do is to minimize the distance between the Frobenius norm of a PSD matrix and a real positive value, which can be formulated as
$$\min \left|\|\textbf{P}\|_F - J\right|^2$$
where $\textbf{P}$ is the PSD matrix to be optimized and $J$ is a real positive constant. Then the problem here is that the whole minimization will fail the disciplined convex programming rule, and I want to know whether we can formulate this idea to be a convex formulation and accepted by CVX. Is it possible to do that?

---

Edit: $\textbf{P}\in \mathbb{C}^{J \times J}$.

Comment: Can you diagonalize the matrix beforehand? Then you can just work on the eigenvalues with a positivity constraint and massively reduce your dimensionality

Comment: You don't have a convex objective function being minimized, so it won't be possible to formulate this in DCP.

Comment: @whpowell96 Really thanks for the comment. It is a good option, but for my specific problem, the PSD matrix that to be optimized has nontrivial off-diagonal entries, so I don't think I can directly diagonalize here.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Really thanks for the comment. Yes, unfortunately it's a nonconvex problem here. I was just trying my luck, maybe  there are some tricks to approximate this nonconvex problem to convex that I just don't know. Right now, it seems I should try some nonconvex solver.

Comment: What does it mean to "optimize" your matrix? You want to find the closest PSD matrix to some initial $P$ that satisfies $\|P\| = J$? It's not clear what properties an optimal solution to your problem should have

Comment: I am not sure you can do what you want. The Frobenius norm is the trace of P^TP. Given an optimum P, I can add epsilon to an eigenvalue of P^TP if I remove epsilon from another, and that remains an optimum. This to me indicates the problem is not convex (at least not strictly convex).

Comment: @whpowell96 Yes, I want to have a PSD that satisfies $\|\textbf{P}\|_F = J$ and subjects to other constraints when using SDR, which I didn't show in the question, as other constraints are convex. Other constrains are like, diganoal values of the PSD to be all 1, and offdiagnoal entries are located in a convex polygon, where the vertices of this regular polygon is on a unit circle, which indicates $\|\textbf{P}\|_F \leq J$, and so on. So, with this Frobenius norm constraint, I aim for a PSD matrix that optimizes the phase of each entry more and subjects to other constraints.

Comment: @Sardine Yes, it seems to be a nonconvex problem right now.

Comment: Yes, this is just as non-convex here as it was at https://ask.cvxr.com/t/is-it-possible-to-formulate-a-convex-expression-to-minimize-the-difference-between-the-frobenious-norm-of-a-positive-semidefinite-matrix-and-a-real-positive-value/12035/2 .

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Thanks again Mark :D, already trying yalmip to solve the problem. Still, taking my chance to see whether there will be a approximation to be convex (doesn't seem likely).

Answer (score 2):

One solution to the problem is to choose $P$ as the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries equal to $J/\sqrt{n}$. Its Frobenius norm is $J$ and it is symmetric and positive definite.

Comment: I suppose the real question is what extra conditions $P$ must satisfy to make this nontrivial. Should it be minimally distant from the some initial $P_0$? Otherwise you can just always choose a trivial solution.

Comment: Really thanks for the answer. Yes, that will be great, but for my specific problem, I have a PSD with nontrivial offdiagonal entries. So, still thinking whether I can approximate this problem to be convex and solve it.